# Installing PlatformIO - platformio not in path

Tags: pip

I know I'm missing something obvious here but...

After following the installation instructions for [PlatformIO](http://platformio.org/) (using the install script):

```
$ platformio
```

gives

```
command not found: platformio
```

Same results using `pip install platformio` (probably what the script uses in the first place, but I thought I'd try anyways)

Answer (score 0):

Please config your CLI tools via this methods:

https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/installation.html#install-shell-commands

for example:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/.platformio/penv/bin
```

see the link for details